# ReportViewer Not working correctly after site published

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Problem:

We have a asp.net reportviewer that is dynamically assigned a dataset to the .rdlc, on my localmachine it works perfectly fine, when we publish to the webserver and attempt to run it an error occurs.

Error:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
    The report definition for report 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\WRIGHTACUMATICA\rErrorCompilation.rdlc' has not been specified
        Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\WRIGHTACUMATICA\rErrorCompilation.rdlc'.
```

Additional Information:

The directory specified in the error is not on the server.
temp is the dataset being assigned.

C#:

```
this.rvErrorCompilation.Reset();
                    this.rvErrorCompilation.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/rErrorCompilation.rdlc");
                    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsErrorCompilation", temp);
                    this.rvErrorCompilation.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    this.rvErrorCompilation.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                    this.rvErrorCompilation.DataBind();
                    this.rvErrorCompilation.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Asp.Net:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvErrorCompilation" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="rErrorCompilation.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Question:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How may I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft visual studio was apparently not copying over the .rdlc file on publish even though it was specified to do so, after manually moving it over to the web root it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `ReportPath="~/rErrorCompilation.rdlc"`

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvErrorCompilation" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="~/rErrorCompilation.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: wouldnt the this.rvErrorCompilation.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/rErrorCompilation.rdlc"); in my backend code override the asp.net in essence doing what you posted?